# PDFKit wkhtmltopdf :root_url Unknown long argument --root-url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'am trying to use the `:root_url` parameter with `PDFKit` like suggested here https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit in **Resolving relative URLs and protocols** section:

```
PDFKit.new(html, root_url: 'http://example.com/').to_file
```

My code:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://stackoverflow.com"))
PDFKit.new(html.to_s, root_url:'http://stackoverflow.com/').to_file(file.path)
```

returns `wkhtmltopdf` error `Unknown long argument --root-url`. It looks like `wkhtmltopdf` doesn't even have such option, and it should be interpreted by the `PDFKit`.

Does anyone know how can I resolve this?

versions: wkhtmltopdf **0.12.4** pdfkit **0.8.2**
tested also with wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 pdfkit 0.8.0

Answer (score 3):

I got the above error once

I have fixed by this way

Execute and copy the path from below command

```
which wkhtmltopdf
```

Create `config/initializers/pdfkit.rb`:

```
 PDFKit.configure do |config|
   config.wkhtmltopdf = '/path/to/wkhtmltopdf'
 end
```

Maybe help you to resolve it

also please use updated version of wkhtmlpdf

as per suggested [here](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/wiki/Troubleshooting#unknown-long-argument---disable-smart-shrinking)

Comment: Thanks for Your suggestion, unhappily that doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Please https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/wiki/Troubleshooting#unknown-long-argument---disable-smart-shrinking look into this and update wkhtmltopdf

Comment: suggest you can you plese try pdfkit 0.8.0 and wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3..Please let me know

Comment: I am geting the same error with pdfkit 0.8.0 and wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3

Comment: can you please also kept `config.root_url = "http://stackoverflow.com/"` in the initializer ...you tried?

Comment: It's not working - I am getting `network error: ContentNotFoundError` which means it still tries to access relative urls.

Answer (score 1):

`wkhtmltopdf` has been reported with some problems recently. Instead of that, please install `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gem & give a try again. (No need to uninstall `wkhtmltopdf`)

```
gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary
```

If it doesn't work solely, try following.

```
PDFKit.new('http://stackoverflow.com').to_file(file.path)
```

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was adding "base" tag directly to HTML.

```
require 'open-uri'
html = open("http://stackoverflow.com").read
html.gsub! "<head>", "<head><base href='http://stackoverflow.com' />"
PDFKit.new(html).to_file("/tmp/out.pdf")
```